# How to use "BACKUP DATABASE", but the database is in a different server.?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have 3 servers ( SQL SERVER 2008 ). Is there a way to backup a database, connected in a different server?

Example: i'm on SQL1. I want to do something like this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [SQL2].DATABASENAME
     TO DISK ='BACKUP SERVER'
```

If there's a way to do this via T-SQL It would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend is cmdline tools

1. SQLCMD in SSMS :

   ```
   :connect sql1\instance1
   BACKUP DATABASE DATABASENAME
    TO DISK ='BACKUP SERVER'

   :connect sql2\instance2 
   BACKUP DATABASE DATABASENAME
    TO DISK ='BACKUP SERVER'
   ```
2. [PowerShell](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1862/backup-sql-server-databases-with-a-windows-powershell-script/)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I don't know What I did wrong but it has a "sintax error" in ':'. I will read the blog to fix this. I could do the task with Aaron's answer.

Comment: You have to enable [sqlcmd mode in SSMS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx).

Comment: Yes. Dumb Me. it worked too. Thank you. I will use the simple EXEC because programmers will use it in a backup software.

Answer (score 3):

You can use SQLCMD Mode in SSMS with :CONNECT and servername\instance to connect to particular server and run your command.

Navigate to SQLCOMD Mode:Open New Query > SQLCMD Mode

just type in query in following format if you have multiple servers to connect and take backup. [image]

```
:CONNECT SQL2

BACKUP DATABASE DATABASENAME
TO DISK ='C:\'

:CONNECT SQL3

BACKUP DATABASE DATABASENAME
     TO DISK ='C:\'
```

Comment: opps .. backups on `C:\` system drive ?

Comment: Haha Thanks. It worked too. I will just not use C: as a backup driver.

Comment: @Kin its just for example purpose.

Answer (score 3):

```
EXEC SQL2.master.sys.sp_executesql N'BACKUP DATABASE dbname 
  TO DISK = N''D:\path_on_remote_server\...'';';
```